# Why does Detritus not become disabled in daylight?

Tags: discworld

It is established in novels such as *The Light Fantastic* and *Moving Pictures* that Discworld trolls turn to stone in daylight, or at least become disabled, and become active at night. This does not seem to happen for Detritus, particularly when he becomes part of the Watch. Why can Detritus function while the sun is up?

My only guess is that he wears a sort of sun block like the trolls Rock and Morry from *Moving Pictures*.

Comment: That would be correct. There's special "cream" or oil trolls put on to be able to walk during the day. It's first mentioned in Moving Pictures and was expensive then. I guess it got cheaper as trolls got more accepted in society.

Comment: Have you gotten to *Thief of Time* and *Night Watch*?

Comment: @derobert Not yet

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Cuddy made him a clockwork cooling helmet during Men at Arms which, along with the barrier cream mentioned in Moving Pictures will keep him more active in the heat.

However, (spoiler)

> the helmet fails in the Desert in Jingo, once again turning him to stone.

(It gets a bit awkward to lose recurring characters for half the active period of any story unless it's convenient to the plot as per Light Fantastic/Jingo. Pratchett had a tendency to favour the story over consistency, hence trolls turn to stone in Light Fantastic, in later books that's no longer useful.)

Comment: I suppose I didn’t know this because I skipped a lot of books to read the first three of the City Watch

Comment: On a side note... in one of the books Detritus got trapped in a freezer, and got super-smart and started doing complex calculations... he didn't finish them, because he froze solid, and when they thawed him up, he was already too hot (read: stupid) and couldn't remember nor understand what he did. I can't remember which book that was in tho...

Comment: It was in Men At Arms. The scene took place in the Pork Futures Warehouse on Morpork Road.

Comment: @IanBush, importantly, it was the event that caused Cuddy to create the cooling helmet

Comment: @Neithan, Detritus is a long term character even before he joins the watch, he appears in Guards Guards as the bouncer at the drum, then in Moving Pictures he gets his first real character development when he meets Ruby.

Comment: Isn't there a tvtropes about things convenient to the plot?

Comment: I'd say that the early books are only partly canon for the later books.  PTerry has said that his early work wasn't of the same quality as his later work as far as having a plot and so on.  As [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170704/why-does-detritus-not-turn-to-stone-during-the-day/170732#170732) points out, after Guards, Guards / Moving Pictures, canon was pretty consistent.  But before that there were lots of things that got thrown out.

Comment: before the helmet, and even a bit after, detritus was part of the NIGHTwatch.

Comment: Re "losing recurring characters for half the active period" - Well, you lose *humans* for about 1/3 of the total period of the story, and nobody seems to have a problem writing that... I think the real issue is that the trolls' sleep cycle is not aligned with a typical human sleep cycle, and there aren't enough of them to carry a nights-only story by themselves, so you have to work around the mismatch more creatively.

Comment: @John, I think you need to read Men at Arms again.

Comment: @Kevin, a lot of police type stories, including these, have a trope of how much sleep characters are missing to get the job done, having a character who just stops at sunrise isn't helpful unless it's helpful (see Vimes 6pm curfew in later books), everyone else has to be seen to be available 24/8 regardless of personal needs.

Comment: @Separatrix: It is entirely possible to write a [crime-fighting story with characters who consistently turn to stone during the day](https://thesffblog.com/2017/03/gargoyles-a-review/).  Pratchett was certainly skilled enough to pull that off.  But then you have to sacrifice a great deal of flexibility in other parts of the plot, and evidently PTerry didn't consider it a worthwhile tradeoff.

Comment: @WayneWerner isn’t that almost every TV-trope?

Answer (score 23):

## Caution : wet paint

When reading Discworld series, There is basically two important stepstones :

- Equal Rites/Mort.
- Guards,Guards/Moving pictures.

For each of this stepstones, there is a before and an after.
This is very flagrant in the Light Fantastic : Independent novels linked by Rincewind with full fantasy elements that will never be heard again.
You might even look at the 2 first book as an 'invented story' that either Rincewind or TwoFlowers will later tell.
As a matter of fact, when asking a new reader to start the series, fans frequently advise to start with Mort.

Guards is the first Vimes book, Pictures is the first New Unseen Academy book. Guards is the time Vetinari is really given a character (Pratchett will later admit the previous Patrician is also Vetinari, yet admitting the retcon.. I will try to find the citation).

So basically : 
Don't try to compare anything from the 3 first book to the rest.
Be tolerant about what you read in the 7 first book to the rest.
The universe was not ready, the paint was wet.

Comment: This is the real answer.  PTerry didn't even try to stay consistent with the first 2 books in lots of ways.  I'm glad he didn't try to paper over things he wanted to change, and instead just ignored them and wrote the stories he thought would be good.  (And BTW, having recently re-read the first several books in the series, I was surprised how consistent Mort is with later canon.  I'd second the recommendation for that as a starting point.  Good and consistent plot.  Eric is another sort of series of short stories like the first 2 Rincewind books.  Fun but skipable.)

Answer (score 22):

[Discworld trolls](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Trolls) differ from the standard fantasy trolls. While the latter are permanently turned to stone by daylight, the trolls on Discworld are (reversibly) affected by heat: The hotter it gets, the slower their silicon-based brains work, up to a complete freeze by overheating.

Trolls coming to Ankh-Morpork are usually the smarter ones and thus have an edge at resisting the day heat. In addition, heat protections like sun shades or heat blocking creams (as mentioned above by jo1storm) or behaviour adaptions (e.g. working in the night) help. In particular, Detritus wears a helmet with a cooling fan.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, trolls on diskworld are not on heat turning into stone (since they are already made out of stone) - they get more stupid. I guess Pratchett got that idea from PCs and laptops. The hotter a CPU is, slower the PC works, and at high enough temperature it shut down.

In [Jingo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jingo_(novel)), Detritus gets stupid during daytime, and smarter during night when it gets cold. Even the cooling helmet didn't help.

Comment: In _The Light Fantastic_ trolls turning to stone in the sun is fairly i,portante to the plot.

Comment: @Neithan trolls don't really "turn to stone", they _are_ stones, just clever ones. As long as it's not too hot, anyway.

Comment: @Erik Okay, that’s correct. This answer seems to be saying that they don’t usually get completely disabled, which seems to be incorrect to me based on the books I’ve read so far.

Comment: @Neithan My understanding is that they are not completely disabled, but I may be wrong. As I said, Pratchett probably used CPU's functionality as how trolls work, therefore it may be possible that they are disabled at high temperature. On the other hand, Detritus became really smart when he got cooled down (forgot in which book). In jingo, he also got bit smarter during night.

Comment: Off topic here, but – CPUs don't work slower when they're hot. CPUs always work as fast as the clock demands. Under normal operation, you may be _effectively_ right because when approaching a critical temperature, the frequency governor could need to turn down the frequency to prevent overheating (but is this actually done? In my experience the computer will spin up the fan and only when it gets outright dangerous, _shut down everything_ to prevent meltdown). But that only applies when the heat comes from the processor itself; against heat from the environment, reducing frequency is futile.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, right. I meant this: https://superuser.com/questions/3371/does-overheating-cause-a-computer-to-slow-down

Comment: @leftaroundabout - CPU frequency governers aside (which are a more modern innovation than the books we're discussing, so can't have inspired anything), logic gates (usually) operate faster when at lower temperatures.  If you want to overclock a processor, you'll be able to get it to run faster if you can keep it cooler (although making it run faster will make it heat up faster, so it's a losing battle), because that makes the logic gates inside it switch faster.  This has been known long enough for Pratchett to have used it for inspiration...

Comment: ... see [this datasheet for example](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/15431/PHILIPS/74F381.html), describing an ALU that was commonly used in minicomputers in the 1970s and 1980s, and see the list of propagation delays on page 7: there are two columns, one for the timings at 25 degrees, and one for timings at 70 degrees, which are a bit slower.  If you really needed a fast calculation, you kept your chips cool...

Comment: @Jules quite possibly. (Are you sure this is at all true for modern processors though? I seem to vaguely recall that this temperature dependence is a characteristic feature of TTL logic and not relevant for CMOS, but I might be wrong here.)

Comment: It is a characteristic of semiconductors so yes... The hotter they get the "slower" they become. This is seen as an increase in propagation delay. When designing chips such delays are taken into account during their static timing analysis across the operating temp

Comment: motherboards (usually needed to use a CPU) will monitor and throttle back clock speed when they detect high heat (cpu as well as ambient), and as well there are internal CPU safety limits which will do the same. both these mechanisms have been around for years.